# bitwise_and two images and counting the resulting objects

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to to get the number of correct answers given a sample of the model answer and an answer sheet example so i'm using `cv2.bitwise_and` function then i'm making erosion and dilation for the resulting image to count the objects that represent the correct answers but it's not working well.
Here is two examples images that i'm using:

[image]

[image]

That is the result:

[image]

so it detect 3 circles instead of 2. I tried to change the number of iterations in erosion and dilation and change the shape of the `StructuringElement` but still getting that wrong answers.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image 
img1 = cv2.imread("model_c3.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("ex_c3.png")

retval1, img1 = cv2.threshold(img1,225,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
retval2, img2 = cv2.threshold(img2,225,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img1gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

mask = cv2.bitwise_and(img1gray, img2gray,img2)

el = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
e = cv2.erode(mask, el, iterations=2)
d = cv2.dilate(e, el, iterations=7)

im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    d,
    cv2.RETR_LIST,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
)

centers = []
radii = []
for contour in contours:    
    br = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    m = cv2.moments(contour)
    center = (int(m['m10'] / m['m00']), int(m['m01'] / m['m00']))
    centers.append(center)

print("There are {} circles".format(len(centers)))    


cv2.imshow('result.png',d)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things in your code.

It doesn't make much sense to threshold the RGB image and then convert it to gray.
Instead of ANDing both images and then do morphological operations to clean the result you should simply prepare both images for a proper AND operation. Make the circles in one image bigger and in the other image smaller. That way you also compensate the small shift you have between both images (the reason for all the artifacts in your AND result).

I'm not sure if you fully understand the functions you use because you use them in a weird manner with strange parameters...

Please note that I just changed a few things in your code to make it work. This is not intended to be a perfect solution.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
#from PIL import Image
img1 = cv2.imread("d://1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("d://2.png")

img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img1gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval1, img1bin = cv2.threshold(img1gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
retval2, img2bin = cv2.threshold(img2gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

el = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
e = cv2.erode(img1bin, el, iterations=2)
cv2.imshow("e", e)
d = cv2.dilate(img2bin, el, iterations=7)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(e, d)
cv2.imshow("d", d)

im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    result,
    cv2.RETR_LIST,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
)

centers = []
radii = []
for contour in contours:
    br = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    m = cv2.moments(contour)
    center = (int(m['m10'] / m['m00']), int(m['m01'] / m['m00']))
    centers.append(center)

print("There are {} circles".format(len(centers)))


cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems the false positive blob is smaller than the other blobs. Filter the contours by area...

```
area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
```

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: I tried this but not all true positive blobs in other images are bigger than the false positive ones.It increased the error in some images